# Self signed Apache cert error: asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-ssl

Can anyone see where I went wrong on these steps (on Windows XP + Apache 2.2)?

I tried to create my own self signed SSL certificate with my own CA and when its all done my Apache server wont start and my log file says:

```
[info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 136 bytes of entropy
[info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file C:/Apache2.2/conf/thor.mysite.com_cert/ksb_cert_rep.p12
[error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

Here is what I did to create the cert:

```
openssl req -x509 -out ca_cert.pem -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ca_priv_key.pem -days 3650
openssl x509 -in ca_cert.pem -text -noout
openssl req -out ksb_cert_req.pem -new -keyout ksb_priv_key.pem
openssl req -noout -text -verify -in ksb_cert_req.pem
openssl x509 -req -in ksb_cert_req.pem -CA ca_cert.pem -CAkey ca_priv_key.pem -CAcreateserial -out ksb_cert_rep.pem -days 3650
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ksb_cert_rep.pem -inkey ksb_priv_key.pem -out ksb_cert_rep.p12 -name "ksb certificate"
openssl pkcs12 -info -in ksb_cert_rep.p12
openssl rsa -in ksb_priv_key.pem -out ksb_priv_key_nopass.pem
```

Also, here is the config in my Apache httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache2.2/conf/ksb_cert_rep.p12"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache2.2/conf/ksb_priv_key_nopass.pem"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache doesn't like PKCS12 format certificates, it [expects x509](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile).  Use your `ksb_cert_rep.pem` file, instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: I also suspect what while its true that on Windows , Apache expects x509, on linux, this is not the case?

Comment: @djangofan What makes you think that?